# Behaviour of generator in lambda safe against future changes?

Tags: python, lambda, generator, yield, readline

I have the following function:

```
|    def line_reader_iter(file_object):
|       while True:
|           a_line = file_object.readline()
|           if len(a_line)==0: raise StopIteration
|           yield a_line[:-1]
```

and somewhere I say:

```
|    line_reader = lambda: next(line_reader_iter(infile))
```

Clearly, the lambda only works because there seems to be a difference in compile-time vs. run-time behaviour which is very welcome: the line_reader_iter() puts the reference to the iterator object into the lambda expression instead of the creation of a generator object each time the lambda is evaluated. BUT: is this portable and stable behaviour? I am just a Python novice and I don't know if my code is in a grey area with respect to the Python execution model. Can someone enligthen me?

slarti

Comment: Generally speaking: Python's semantics and even syntax is largely stable, and changes (mostly additions) are backwards-compatible. An exception was made when 3.0 was created (3.x is again backwards-compatible, only regarding 3.0 instead of 2.x), but even that changed nothing fundamental, and certainly nothing you touch on in this piece of code. That said, your guess at why this works is wrong, but this has been answered by the time I was done writing :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are actually misunderstanding why this works.  Each time you call `line_reader()` a new `line_reader_iter` generator ***is*** created.  It appears to work because you use the same `infile` each time, and each call to `readline()` will return the next line of the file.

Consider the following simpler example:

```
>>> counter = lambda: next(iter(range(10)))
>>> counter()
0
>>> counter()    # each time the lambda is called, a new range iter is created
0
```

You can get the behavior you want by using the following:

```
line_reader = line_reader_iter(infile).next
```

Here is how this would work with my range example:

```
>>> counter = iter(range(10)).next
>>> counter()
0
>>> counter()    # yay, we are actually using the same iterator
1
```

Comment: And in fact, `line_reader_iter()` is redundant since files already yield lines when iterated over.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - It isn't completely redundant, `line_reader_iter()` automatically strips off the newline, iterating over the file does not.

Comment: minor nitpick: I think one has to use the internal next of the generator object: line_reader = line_reader_iter(infile).__next__

Comment: @slartibartfast - Thanks, after some investigation it looks like `next` needs to be used for Python 2.x, and `__next__` is necessary for 3.x.